# Разница между виджетами: QMainWindow и QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Скажите, почему не отображается окно, когда наследуемся от

```
class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    ...
```

и работает, когда наследуемся от

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    ...
```

---

---

**`Работает`**: наследуем от `QWidget`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFrame, QPushButton

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button_hello = QPushButton('Hello')
        self.button_hello.clicked.connect(self.add_button)

        self.layout_buttons = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_buttons.addStretch()  # Это добавит пружину, прижимающую виджеты вверх

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout_buttons)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_hello)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_button(self):
        button = QPushButton('Кнопка')
        self.layout_buttons.insertWidget(0, button)  # Добавление в начало, с пружиной это прижмет вверх
        # self.layout_buttons.addWidget(button)  # Добавление в конец, с пружиной это прижмет вниз


app = QApplication([])
mw = MyWidget()
mw.show()
app.exec()
```

**`Не работает`**: наследуем от `QMainWindow`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFrame, QPushButton

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button_hello = QPushButton('Hello')
        self.button_hello.clicked.connect(self.add_button)

        self.layout_buttons = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_buttons.addStretch()  # Это добавит пружину, прижимающую виджеты вверх

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout_buttons)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_hello)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_button(self):
        button = QPushButton('Кнопка')
        self.layout_buttons.insertWidget(0, button)  # Добавление в начало, с пружиной это прижмет вверх
        # self.layout_buttons.addWidget(button)  # Добавление в конец, с пружиной это прижмет вниз


app = QApplication([])
mw = MyWidget()
mw.show()
app.exec()
```

**P.S.** коды различаются только в одной строке:
`class MyWidget(QWidget или QMainWindow):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMainWindow имеет свой собственный макет. Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFrame, QPushButton

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MyWidget(QMainWindow):                                                 # - QWidget 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                       # +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                            # +++
        

        self.button_hello = QPushButton('Hello')
        self.button_hello.clicked.connect(self.add_button)

        self.layout_buttons = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_buttons.addStretch()  # Это добавит пружину, прижимающую виджеты вверх

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout_buttons)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)                    # + self.centralWidget
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_hello)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.frame)

#        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_button(self):
        button = QPushButton('Кнопка')
        self.layout_buttons.insertWidget(0, button)  # Добавление в начало, с пружиной это прижмет вверх
        # self.layout_buttons.addWidget(button)  # Добавление в конец, с пружиной это прижмет вниз


app = QApplication([])
mw = MyWidget()
mw.show()
app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Потому что классу `QMainWindow` (в отличии от `QWidget`) нельзя устанавливать layout.

```
class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        wid = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        self.lay = QVBoxLayou() # a layout
        wid.setLayout(self.lay)
        ...
```

Comment: Он уже там есть;)

Comment: @eri Ну да. Поэтому установить нельзя.